# Integrating $\int\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I came across a question today...

> Find $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}\,dx$$

How to do this? I tried to take $x^4+1=u^2$ but no result. Then I tried to take $x^2+1=\frac{1}{u}$, but even that didn't work. Then I manipulated it to $\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\,dx+\int\dfrac{2}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{1+x^4}}\,dx$, butI have no idea  how to solve it.

Wolframalpha gives some [imaginary result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%5E2-1)%2F((x%5E2%2B1)(sqrt(x%5E4%2B1))))...but the answer is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\arccos\dfrac{x\sqrt2}{x^2+1}+C$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint** Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, to get:
$$\int \frac{(1-\frac{1}{x^2})dx}{(x+\frac{1}{x})(\sqrt {(x+\frac{1}{x})^2-2} )}$$
Then put $x+\frac{1}{x}=t$
$$\int \frac{dt}{t(\sqrt{t^2-2})}$$
Which is easily taken care of by putting $t=\sqrt2 \sec\theta$, 
$$\int \frac{(\sqrt2 \sec\theta\tan \theta)d\theta}{\sqrt2 \sec\theta \sqrt2 \tan\theta}$$

Comment: Very clever! +1

Comment: @zz20s Thanks!, btw someone was editing this,  what was it?, I was adding something at that time!

Comment: I just removed some unnecessary brackets. If you'd prefer to keep them, that's okay. Either way, great answer.

Comment: Thanks...today I found out that even WA can be wrong.. :)

Comment: @manshu I won't say that it can be *wrong*, could you post the result alpha gives?

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%5E2-1)%2F((x%5E2%2B1)(sqrt(x%5E4%2B1))))

Comment: @manshu I take my words back

Comment: Setting $\sqrt{t^2-2}=u\implies\dfrac t{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt=du, t^2=u^2+2$ $$\int\dfrac{dt}{t\sqrt{t^2-2}}=\int\dfrac{t\ dt}{t^2\sqrt{t^2-2}}=\int\dfrac{du}{u^2+2}=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\arctan u$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee *$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1}\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @Nikunj, True & right

Answer (score 4):

With (this seem to be some kind of [substitution of the day](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1679918/97236))
$$
t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}
$$
you get
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+2t^2}\,dt.
$$
I'm sure you can take it from here.